# Array doesent update values

Tags: javascript

I want my array to be updated as soon as I run the replace function. What actually happens is that all the elements of my array get deleted here is the code:

```
var Person = [];
var editPersonId = 0;
var Details = [];

function AddPerson() {

    this.Details[0] = document.getElementById("fname").value; 
    this.Details[1] = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    this.Details[2] = document.getElementById("age").value;
    this.Details[3] = document.getElementById("mobil").value;
    this.Details[4] = document.getElementById("adress").value; 
    Person.push(this.Details);            
}
function Clear(){
    document.getElementById("fname").value = ""; 
    document.getElementById("lname").value = "";
    document.getElementById("age").value ="";
    document.getElementById("mobil").value = "";
    document.getElementById("adress").value = ""; 
}

function ShowContacts(){
    var testIt= document.getElementById("search").value;
    var i=0, k=0, indx=[], msg;
        for ( i=0; i < Person.length; i++) 
        { 
            for ( k=0; k<=4; k++)   
            { 
                if (Person[i][k] === testIt)
                {
                document.getElementById("newFname").value = Person[i][0];
                document.getElementById("newLname").value = Person[i][1];
                document.getElementById("newAge").value = Person[i][2];
                document.getElementById("newMobil").value = Person[i][3];
                document.getElementById("newAdress").value = Person[i][4];
                console.log(1);
                editPersonId = i;
                break;
                }
            }
        }   
    }

function Replace(){
    Person[editPersonId][0] = document.getElementById("newFname").value;
    Person[editPersonId][1] = document.getElementById("newLname").value;
    Person[editPersonId][2] = document.getElementById("newAge").value;
    Person[editPersonId][3] = document.getElementById("newMobil").value;
    Person[editPersonId][4] = document.getElementById("newAdress").value;
}


function Run(){
    this.AddPerson();
    this.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what functions will be executed? If it's only `Run()`, the Array should not be empty.

Comment: run and replace...sorry btw for the code Im new to programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You override the contents of your `Person` insde of `replace()`.

```
 Person[editPersonId][0] = ...
```

While `editPersonId` is `0`, means that the item you inserted in `AddPerson` will be overriden. And before `replace()`, you run `clear()`, which empties your inputs. So the elements don't get 'deleted', you replace them with an empty string.

You might wanna look into [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)